# JQuery mobile position of the $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I've scoured them web but can't find anything on this.
I'm using the JQuery Mobile `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg` effectively.
However a few pages on my web app are loaded via AJAX with dynamic content
into the `listviews` JQuery Mobile offers. When I scroll down on the app,
and then click a list item it goes to another page but the app automatically kicks 
the view back to the top (original loaded view) and seems to hang to the average user but
you know the `` `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg `` is being shown below the current viewport. Is there a way I can have the message dialog show center screen no matter how far the user scrolls down?

Answer (score 0):

Try this when manipulating the layout via ajax or animations...

```
$(document).trigger('updatelayout');
```

Comment: I added it the head of the page I was having issues with, it did not work unless I'm using it wrong. Seems that it auto scrolls to the top on a button click.